# Programming Assignment: What data type should method be to return an array and error in method?

Tags: java, class, methods

I have the following code:

```
public class Bank
{
   private BankAccount[] bank;
   private int pointer = 0;
   public Bank()
   {
      bank = new BankAccount[10];
   }


   public void addAccount(BankAccount bankAccount)
   {
      for(int pointer = 0; pointer <= 10; pointer ++)
      {
         bank[pointer] = bankAccount;
      }
   }


   public type getAccount(int i)
   {
      return BankAccount[i];
   }
```

The return for the getAccount method is causing me issues.

The requirement for the method is as follows:

- The method getAccount will return a BankAccount object given an integer index value as a parameter.

The BankAccount object is in another class and works perfectly. I am getting the error of **Cannot find symbol** with a carrot at BankAccount. I am not sure why this is.

So my question is: Why isn't it finding the BankAccount object, and what type should it return?

Comment: Your code has a number of problems but the principal one is `public type getAccount(int i)`.  The word `type` here is what you shoujld have replaced with the type to be returned.  It is giving you the error because `type` is just a meaningless placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `getAccount` method should return a `BankAccount` type (using the `bank` object. So, it should be like this:

```
   public BankAccount getAccount(int i)
   {
      return bank[i];
   }
```

Comment: Maybe. Why? What did you change? *Why* did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I don't understand what are you trying to say! His problem is with the getAccount method.

Comment: I was saying that you hadn't explained anything. Now you've edited, you've at least *slightly* explained (though only very slightly).

Answer (score -1):

> Why isn't it finding the `BankAccount` object...

Because there is no `BankAccount` object. There's a `BankAccount` *class*, but your instances of it (objects) are held in `bank`. That's where you want to get them from.

> ...and what type should it return?

Well, the purpose of the method is to get the account, so there's one type in your code that would be suitable to that. (And yes, I'm being deliberately vague because it'll be more valuable to you if I *help* you get there rather than just telling you.)

Note that to signal an error getting the account, you wouldn't typically *return* something*, you'd *throw an error* (an "exception") instead.

---

Side note: Never do this:

```
bank = new BankAccount[10];
```

then later

```
for(int pointer = 0; pointer <= 10; pointer ++)
```

First off, your loop is going too far (there is no `bank[10]` entry in that array). Second off, if you ever change the length of `bank`, now you have to do it in *two* places. Instead of `<= 10`, use `< bank.length`:

```
for(int pointer = 0; pointer < bank.length; pointer ++)
```

---

* *(he said speaking very generally and allowing for the fact there are exceptions to every rule)*